# Relationship between aspiration and career

Tags: the-sims-2

I found a few guides that state that some careers are better suited for specific type of aspiration.

For example the Slacker is better suited for the Romance aspiration.

My question is: what is the specific effect that aspirations have over career? Do aspirations improve the chance of promotion for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far it seems there are no specific effects.
The only thing is that the life aspiration includes something like "reach the last stage in the XXX career".